# How can I show a spinner while the server generates a PDF file for the user?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, user-interface

I'm using Spring MVC to present the user with a form that has a series of options. When they submit the form, the options are used to generate a PDF file. In some cases, generation of the PDF file takes a while — 30 seconds or more.

When the PDF is generated, it comes down as an `Application/PDF` that the user can save.

I'd like to show an animation while the PDF is being generated. At the moment, the only indication that the server is working is the `Waiting for ...` shown in the browser.

Comment: Use AJAX instead of doing a direct post and redraw.  Then you can pop a "waiting" widget and allow the download to happen in the background.

Comment: So the AJAX request will fetch the PDF file as its result — how do I then make that available as a download?

Comment: If you make an HTTP request that returns a PDF, the browser should prompt the user to save it.